# Determine whether an nestead array contains a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array:

```
var arr = [['blue','143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];
```

Now I need to check `red` is exist in the `0` index of nested array?

---

There is a method  in JQuery `$.inArray(value, array)` which can be fine in this case. But I don't know how use it to just search in this items:

```
var arr = [['blue','143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];
// these       ^              ^                ^
```

How can I do that?

---

I want this:

```
var word = 'red';    // true
var word = 'black';  // false
var word = 'blue';   // true
var word = 'afwqwe'; // false
```

Comment: And what have you tried other then jquery?

Comment: @Amit To be honest, I searched very much .. But all approaches are using `indexOf ` and I really don't want that. Because the most my website's users use *IE7*

Comment: `while` is available in IE4 if I'm correct. Are you familiar with that? Please show minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that can do that test:

```js
function hasColor(arr, color) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] == color) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// test it
var arr = [['blue','143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];

document.write ('<pre>' +
                '\nred: ' + hasColor(arr, 'red') + 
                '\nblack: ' + hasColor(arr, 'black') + 
                '\nblue: ' + hasColor(arr, 'blue') + 
                '\nafwqwe: ' + hasColor(arr, 'afwqwe') +
                '</pre>');
```

Comment: This would only work if you are only ever searching the first element of each nested array

Comment: Indeed, that is how I understood the question.

Comment: @millerbr Thant's exaclty what I want :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean that as criticism, just a heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this:

```
var arr = [['blue','143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];
var search = function(term) {
    var result = false;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(term == arr[i][j]) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var word = search('red');    // true
var word = search('black');  // false
var word = search('blue');   // true
var word = search('afwqwe'); // false
```

Without `indexOf`, this is a bit less elegant and will probably be quite slow on large arrays, but it will do the trick!

Comment: Thank you .. but I don't want to use `indexOf`, because it doesn't work in IE and old browsers *(the most users of my website use IE7 :P)*

Comment: Ah! then let me do it a different way, be a few minutes!

Comment: @stack switch it out for `$.inArray()` which has cross browser support

Comment: `forEach` is not supported in older browsers without polyfill

Comment: @charlietfl Why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @stack answers with simple `for` loop is all you need

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @charlietfl - I have switched to standard `for` loops

Comment: There's no need for indexOf or $.inArray or a nested loop, because the question says the required strings will always be in the first element of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function check(array, value) {
    return array.some(function (a) {
        return a[0] === value;
    });
}

var arr = [['blue', '143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];

document.write(check(arr, 'red') + '<br>');    // true
document.write(check(arr, 'black') + '<br>');  // false
document.write(check(arr, 'blue') + '<br>');   // true
document.write(check(arr, 'afwqwe') + '<br>'); // false
```

Version without iterator:

```js
function check(array, value) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var arr = [['blue', '143'], ['red', '256'], ['white', '321']];

document.write(check(arr, 'red') + '<br>');    // true
document.write(check(arr, 'black') + '<br>');  // false
document.write(check(arr, 'blue') + '<br>');   // true
document.write(check(arr, 'afwqwe') + '<br>'); // false
```

Comment: @BobbyMatson Yeah exactly